# Double centralizer theorem for semisimple rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Why every semisimple ring has the double centralizer property? Namely,
let $R$ be a semisimple ring. We consider $R$ as left $R$-module. Let $E=End(R)$. Why every element in $End(R_E)$ is induced by  left multiplication?

Comment: So by $End(R)$ you mean the group endomorphisms of $R$?

Comment: Yes, considering R as left R module. Then I consider R as right E module.

Comment: I think "Yes, considering $R$ as a left $R$ module." is a contradictory answer. Do you mean $End(_RR)$ or do you mean $End(_\mathbb ZR)$?

Comment: I mean the first one

Comment: Isn't this Jacobson's density theorem?

Comment: Thank you for the Jacobson's reference! I understand the proof now!